# Pyinstaller Hotkey not working in Exe with pynput module

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, hotkeys, pynput

I was thinking to add a hotkey feature in my project. So I found out that `pynput` can be use to achieve that. I used that and create a test snippet. It is working fine when I am running that as a python script but when I compiled the script to exe using `pyinstaller` as a standalone application, it is not registering the hotkey on key press and not showing any errors while running from `command prompt`. I have tried `keyboard`, `pynput` packages to create a hotkey but unable to fix, why the hotkey is not working in executable mode?

#### Test snippet

```py
from pynput.keyboard import HotKey, Key, KeyCode, Listener
import sys


def function_1():
    print('Function 1 activated')


def function_2():
    sys.exit(0)


hotkey1 = HotKey(
    [Key.ctrl, Key.shift, KeyCode(char='a')],
    function_1
)

hotkey2 = HotKey(
    [Key.ctrl, Key.shift, KeyCode(char='t')],
    function_2
)

hotkeys = [hotkey1, hotkey2]


def signal_press_to_hotkeys(key):
    for hotkey in hotkeys:
        hotkey.press(l.canonical(key))


def signal_release_to_hotkeys(key):
    for hotkey in hotkeys:
        hotkey.release(l.canonical(key))


a = input('Enter something: ')
print(a)

with Listener(on_press=signal_press_to_hotkeys, on_release=signal_release_to_hotkeys) as l:
    l.join()
```

#### Output of python script:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzoaE.png]

#### Output of exported exe file with pyinstaller:

Command used to export: `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`

```
109 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.7
109 INFO: Python: 3.8.10
153 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
154 INFO: wrote E:\Projects (Web-Dev)\Gmoments\window-capture\test\main.spec
157 INFO: UPX is not available.
159 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['E:\\Projects (Web-Dev)\\Gmoments\\window-capture\\test']
434 INFO: checking Analysis
450 INFO: Building because E:\Projects (Web-Dev)\Gmoments\window-capture\test\main.py changed
451 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
454 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
485 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3256 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
3256 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib'
6543 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
6760 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
6763 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\saransh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe
7053 INFO: Analyzing E:\Projects (Web-Dev)\Gmoments\window-capture\test\main.py
7167 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
7359 INFO: Processing module hooks...
7359 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pynput.py' from 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
7684 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7684 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...     
7695 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7698 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...     
7844 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7847 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7958 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7960 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7964 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7965 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7966 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
8098 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
8362 INFO: checking Tree
8462 INFO: checking Tree
8622 INFO: checking Tree
8653 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
8683 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
8689 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
8693 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
8700 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'        
8710 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
8924 INFO: Looking for eggs
8925 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\saransh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python38.dll
8925 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
8932 INFO: Warnings written to E:\Projects (Web-Dev)\Gmoments\window-capture\test\build\main\warn-main.txt
9006 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to E:\Projects (Web-Dev)\Gmoments\window-capture\test\build\main\xref-main.html
9024 INFO: checking PYZ
9032 INFO: Building because toc changed
9033 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) E:\Projects (Web-Dev)\Gmoments\window-capture\test\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz
9656 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) E:\Projects (Web-Dev)\Gmoments\window-capture\test\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
9684 INFO: checking PKG
9689 INFO: Building because toc changed
9689 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) main.pkg
11757 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) main.pkg completed successfully.
11760 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\saransh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
11761 INFO: checking EXE
11763 INFO: Building because toc changed
11764 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
11766 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to E:\Projects (Web-Dev)\Gmoments\window-capture\test\dist\main.exe
11776 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
11777 INFO: Copying icons from ['c:\\users\\saransh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\bootloader\\images\\icon-console.ico']
11782 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 104 bytes
11783 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 3752 bytes
11783 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 2216 bytes
11784 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 1384 bytes
11784 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 37019 bytes
11785 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 9640 bytes
11785 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 4264 bytes
11785 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 1128 bytes
11794 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
11796 INFO: Emedding manifest in EXE
11798 INFO: Updating manifest in E:\Projects (Web-Dev)\Gmoments\window-capture\test\dist\main.exe
11809 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
11814 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
13512 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```